# for embedded loop weird situation

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Why is the j value initially looped twice?
Code:

```
others = 0
for i in range(2):
    print("i:", i)
    for j in range(3):
        print("j:", j)
        if i != j:
            print("i !=j ", i != j)
            others += 1
            print("others: ", others)
else:
    others += 1
    print("others under else: ", others)
print("others on the last line:", others)
```

Output:

```
i: 0
j: 0
j: 1
i !=j  True
others:  1
j: 2
i !=j  True
others:  2
i: 1
j: 0
i !=j  True
others:  3
j: 1
j: 2
i !=j  True
others:  4
others under else:  5
others on the last line: 5

Process finished with exit code 0`
```

I've got no code above it and no code below it. Can't understand what's going on here with j, why the first round j has two print outs 0 and 1??? Help please

Comment: Follow the code step by step at http://pythontutor.com…

Answer (score 0):

The j in the beginning is equal to  variable "i" so the code is ignoring the "if" and increments j to become 1. Afterwards, the j has become 1 and it differs from i so the others is incrementing and that's also the case for j=2  since you have range(3). Then the i increments and the same is happening again. The difference is now that the others variable will not increment when the j is equal to 1 because now i is 1.

The general functionality of this code is that the i is getting the values 0 and then 1 and for these two values the j is getting the values 0,1,2 and when i is not equal to j the others variable is incrementing.

Also in python the indexing matters so make sure that the else is in correct position with its relevant if and also what is the outcome you would like to have.